# AWS Lambda fs.readfile issue

Tags: javascript, file, aws-lambda

I'm packing some files in my lambda package that I need. I've used some example floating around to nearly get it working.

I'm able to verify the path of a file OK

```
const deviceCert = path.resolve(certType + "-deviceCert.key");
```

which logs out to

```
"message": "Resolved path to TEST-deviceCert.key: /var/task/TEST-deviceCert.key"
```

when I attempt to read the file using

```
fs.readFile(deviceCert, (err, data) => {

    if (err) {

        log.error(`Verify deviceCert failure: ${err}`);
        responseBody = Helper.buildCORSResponse(502, JSON.stringify({ message: "Unable to locate file required" }));

        return callback(null, responseBody);

    }

});
```

I get the following error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/TEST-deviceCert.key'"
```

If I can verify the path then why cant I read it?

Any ideas??

Comment: is /var/task/TEST-deviceCert.key deployed within your application?

Comment: I'm currently trying to confirm that. My suspicions are that for some reason the files are not being packaged correctly.

Currently awaiting output of sls package so I can verify

my function has the following defined in serverless.yml

    package:

      indivually: true

      include:

        - src/marlin/Certs/**

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the node.js [path.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) API documentation:

> The path.resolve() method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an absolute path.

In other words, `resolve` concatenates a sequence of strings into one string, formatted as an absolute path. However, it does not check whether or not there is a file at this location. You can use either [fs.stat()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback) or [fs.access()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) to verify the presence and access of the file.

Comment: Thanks matsev

figured that out and have added fs.access and still failing

Currently determining correct packaging of files

Answer (score 0):

eventually confirmed that serverless was packaging the files I needed.

Using fs.readdir I was able to debug the issue and find the path that the packaging process was creating in the Lambda package

/var/task/src//Certs/

Hope this helps someone in the future!!